# How to calculate hash of APK file programmatically?

Tags: android, apk, android-package-managers

I want to calculate the MD5 hash of the APK file from inside the app.

```
PackageInfo info = App.getInstance().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
File file = new File(info.applicationInfo.sourceDir);
String hash = MD5.calculateMD5(file);
```

The MD5 hash is calculated like this:

```
private String calculateMD5() {

    MessageDigest digest;

    try {
        digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        return null;
    }

    InputStream is;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        return null;
    }

    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int read;
    try {
        while ((read = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            digest.update(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        byte[] md5sum = digest.digest();
        BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1, md5sum);
        String output = bigInt.toString(16);
        output = String.format("%32s", output).replace(' ', '0');
        return output;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to process file for MD5", e);
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

However I keep getting the same hash when running in the emulator, even when I change the source code.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Double check that you are truly running against a modified build. I suggest completely uninstalling and then reinstalling after the code change.

Comment: You were right! Clicking "Debug app" was not enough, I had to rebuild the project to get a different hash. You wanna write an answer or should I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check that you are truly running against a modified build. I suggest completely uninstalling and then reinstalling after the code change. I learned this the hard way after debugging an web app for two hours to find that I hadn't deployed the change I made.

Comment: It was enough to rebuild the project to get the new hash value, without uninstalling. After that only hitting "Debug app" was apparently enough to get the new hash, but rebuilding seems to be on the safe side.